# Find next row value using lead

Tags: sql, sql-server, max, lead

I am trying to calculate a validtodate using the lead function. My data can change when a new file is uploaded. This file includes every location which is active in a warehouse.

| ValidFromDate | ValidToDate | Location | AdministrationNr | WarehouseNr | FileName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2-1-2022 | 31-12-9999 | 19-26-2C | 1 | 22 | Locaties_Administratie_001_02-01-2022.txt |
| 11-10-2021 | 1-1-2022 | 19-26-2C | 1 | 22 | Locaties_Administratie_001_11-10-2021.txt |
| 24-8-2021 | 10-10-2021 | 19-26-2C | 1 | 22 | Locaties_Administratie_001_24-08-2021.txt |
| 4-5-2021 | 23-8-2021 | 19-26-2C | 1 | 22 | Locaties_Administratie_001_04-05-2021.txt |
| 15-6-2022 | 31-12-9999 | 21-48-4C | 1 | 22 | Locaties_Administratie_001_15-06-2022.txt |
| 4-1-2022 | 14-6-2022 | 21-48-4C | 1 | 22 | Locaties_Administratie_001_04-01-2022.txt |
| 2-1-2022 | 3-1-2022 | 21-48-4C | 1 | 22 | Locaties_Administratie_001_02-01-2022.txt |
| 11-10-2021 | 1-1-2022 | 21-48-4C | 1 | 22 | Locaties_Administratie_001_11-10-2021.txt |
| 24-8-2021 | 10-10-2021 | 21-48-4C | 1 | 22 | Locaties_Administratie_001_24-08-2021.txt |
| 4-5-2021 | 23-8-2021 | 21-48-4C | 1 | 22 | Locaties_Administratie_001_04-05-2021.txt |
| 15-6-2022 | 31-12-9999 | 21-60-3D | 1 | 22 | Locaties_Administratie_001_15-06-2022.txt |
| 4-1-2022 | 14-6-2022 | 21-60-3D | 1 | 22 | Locaties_Administratie_001_04-01-2022.txt |
| 2-1-2022 | 3-1-2022 | 21-60-3D | 1 | 22 | Locaties_Administratie_001_02-01-2022.txt |
| 11-10-2021 | 1-1-2022 | 21-60-3D | 1 | 22 | Locaties_Administratie_001_11-10-2021.txt |
| 24-8-2021 | 10-10-2021 | 21-60-3D | 1 | 22 | Locaties_Administratie_001_24-08-2021.txt |
| 4-5-2021 | 23-8-2021 | 21-60-3D | 1 | 22 | Locaties_Administratie_001_04-05-2021.txt |

Within this file a date is extracted, the ValidFromDate. Based on this date I want to find the next ValidFromDate to determine till what date this location was active. I did this with the following function:

```
LEAD( DATEADD(DAY, -1, [ValidFromDate]) ,1, '9999-12-31' ) 
OVER (PARTITION BY [AdministrationNr], [WarehouseNr], [Location] 
ORDER BY [ValidFromDate] ASC    ) as ValidToDate
```

However, when a location completely dissapears within the file this results in 9999-12-31. This is correct when the location is in the latest file because this is the active at this moment but this is also the case when a location dissapears in the warehouse.

In this case for location '19-26-2C' I have to find the next file date where it dit not appear in.

By checking whether a ValidFromDate is equal to the maximum date in all rows I can determine if the location is active at the current moment. See code:

```
CASE 
    WHEN ValidFromDate = MAX ( ValidFromDate ) OVER ( PARTITION BY WarehouseNr, AdministrationNr )
    THEN '9999-31-12'
    ELSE -- Next file date
```

All that is left for me is to fill the else statement with the next file date after file: 2022-01-02.

This is date 2022-01-04.

Is there any way for me to find this date?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) If you want to supply sample data, DDL and DML are by far the best way. For expected results, then a markdown table works well.

Comment: This would be much more clear if you would show us some sample data and expected outcome (images for this do not count)

Comment: @GuidoG I Just added a data sample. The first row should not have 31-12-9999 but should get value 3-1-2022.

Comment: Then just change the value in the first row. Or what is your question ?

Comment: @GuidoG  

The ValidToDate is calculated with this statement:

`LEAD( DATEADD(DAY, -1, [ValidFromDate]) ,1, '9999-12-31' ) 
OVER (PARTITION BY [AdministrationNr], [WarehouseNr], [Location] 
ORDER BY [ValidFromDate] ASC    ) as ValidToDate`


For location '19-26-2C' the date 9999-31-12 is not correct. It should be the date 04-01-2022 because this is where the location dissapears in my files. I am looking for the next file date in this case. What formula can I use to get this date?

Comment: What does "next file date" mean? If there is no row then there is no row. Why would you use a different location altogether?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with an `outer apply` in stead of the `lead`

That would look like this

```
select t.ValidFromDate,
       isnull(d.ValidToDate, '99991231') as ValidToDate,
       t.Location,
       t.AdministrationNr,
       t.WareHouseNr,
       t.FileName
from   t
  outer apply ( select top 1
                       dateadd(day, -1, t2.ValidFromDate) as ValidToDate
                from   t as t2
                where  t2.AdministrationNr = t.AdministrationNr
                and    t2.WareHouseNr = t.WareHouseNr
                and    t2.Location = t.Location
                and    t2.ValidFromDate > t.ValidFromDate
                order by t2.ValidFromDate
              ) d
order by t.id
```

See [this DBFiddle to see this in action](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5a5d2859b0e00d7edb10f23f861302b5)

**EDIT**

If you want to use window function, I would use `LAG` in stead of `LEAD`, see this example

```
select t.ValidFromDate,
       dateadd(day, -1, 
         isnull(lag(t.ValidFromDate)
                  over (partition by t.AdministrationNr, t.WareHouseNr, t.Location
                  order by id)
               , '10000101')
              ) as ValidToDate,
       t.Location,
       t.AdministrationNr,
       t.WareHouseNr,
       t.FileName
from   t
order by t.id
```

And [this updated DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fa1ffd4234af97ebbb7f45d34679cca8)

The result looks like this

| ValidFromDate | ValidToDate | Location | AdministrationNr | WareHouseNr | FileName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-02 | 9999-12-31 | 19-26-2C | 1 | 22 | Locaties_Administratie_001_02-01-2022.txt |
| 2021-10-11 | 2022-01-01 | 19-26-2C | 1 | 22 | Locaties_Administratie_001_11-10-2021.txt |
| 2021-08-24 | 2021-10-10 | 19-26-2C | 1 | 22 | Locaties_Administratie_001_24-08-2021.txt |
| 2021-05-04 | 2021-08-23 | 19-26-2C | 1 | 22 | Locaties_Administratie_001_04-05-2021.txt |
| 2022-06-15 | 9999-12-31 | 21-48-4C | 1 | 22 | Locaties_Administratie_001_15-06-2022.txt |
| 2022-01-04 | 2022-06-14 | 21-48-4C | 1 | 22 | Locaties_Administratie_001_04-01-2022.txt |
| 2022-01-02 | 2022-01-03 | 21-48-4C | 1 | 22 | Locaties_Administratie_001_02-01-2022.txt |
| 2021-10-11 | 2022-01-01 | 21-48-4C | 1 | 22 | Locaties_Administratie_001_11-10-2021.txt |
| 2021-08-24 | 2021-10-10 | 21-48-4C | 1 | 22 | Locaties_Administratie_001_24-08-2021.txt |
| 2021-05-04 | 2021-08-23 | 21-48-4C | 1 | 22 | Locaties_Administratie_001_04-05-2021.txt |
| 2022-06-15 | 9999-12-31 | 21-60-3D | 1 | 22 | Locaties_Administratie_001_15-06-2022.txt |
| 2022-01-04 | 2022-06-14 | 21-60-3D | 1 | 22 | Locaties_Administratie_001_04-01-2022.txt |
| 2022-01-02 | 2022-01-03 | 21-60-3D | 1 | 22 | Locaties_Administratie_001_02-01-2022.txt |
| 2021-10-11 | 2022-01-01 | 21-60-3D | 1 | 22 | Locaties_Administratie_001_11-10-2021.txt |
| 2021-08-24 | 2021-10-10 | 21-60-3D | 1 | 22 | Locaties_Administratie_001_24-08-2021.txt |
| 2021-05-04 | 2021-08-23 | 21-60-3D | 1 | 22 | Locaties_Administratie_001 |